# variables scope confusion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was studying the concept of variable scope in JS, found this example on it:

```
(function() {
    var foo = 1;
    function bar() {
        var foo = 2;
    }
    bar();
    console.log(foo) //outputs 1
    if(true) {
        var foo = 3;
    }
    console.log(foo) //outputs 3
})();
```

output of this function is

```
1 
3
```

Now I am confused how come `foo` gets gets value 3 in second log. even when `foo` is declared by using `var` in `if` statement. shouldn't the `foo` declared in `if` will have a new instance as it gets in `bar()`??

Comment: JavaScript has function-level scope, not block-level one. The `var` inside the `if` is counted the same way as the `var foo`.

Comment: Curious why the downvoters are downvoting. It's not a bad question. Duplicate perhaps, but not bad. Some questions deserve both downvotes and close votes. But good questions that have been asked before should be marked as duplicate. And great questions that have been asked before should be marked as duplicate and **upvoted!** This question has a clear and concise code example along with a well articulated question. This is a *great* question, albeit duplicate. The linked duplicate is *not* great: it lacks a code sample and asks multiple questions. Perhaps it should be closed as "too broad". ;)

Comment: I agree, it's a good, duplicate question. I'll upvote and vote for closure then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two kinds of scope in Javascript; function scope and global scope.

The code inside the `if` statement doesn't have a scope of its own, so the variable inside the `if` statement is the same one as the one outside it.

Declaring a variable more than once in a scope doesn't create more than one variable. The `var` keyword inside the `if` statement is ignored as the variable already is declared once in the scope, so it's just an assignment.

---

Note also that the declaration of variables is hoisted to the top of the scope, so even if a declaration is inside a code block that is not executed, the variable is still created:

```
var foo = 1; // a global variable
(function() {
  console.log(foo) //outputs "undefined"
  foo = 2; // sets the local variable
  if(false) {
    var foo = 3; // creates the local variable, but the assignment never happens
  }
  console.log(foo) //outputs 2
})();
console.log(foo) //outputs 1
```

Comment: "There are only two scopes ..."  No.  Two *kinds* of scope would be more accurate, but to say that there are only two scopes is just confusing.

Comment: @gilly3: Yes, you are right, that is clearer.

Answer (score 8):

`if` does not introduce a scope block (I understand it does in some langauges). In JavaScript, only `function() {}` creates a scope block.

Comment: "I understand it does in some langauges" which ones? Just curious...

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#By_language